# Controller as a Service with Command Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have a controller as a Service and I want to call it from my Command

This is my configuration

```
#service.yml
parameters:
       dg_app.controller.glossaries.class: dg\AppBundle\Controller\GlossaryController

services:
    dg.glossary.controller:
        synchronized: true
        class: "%dg_app.controller.glossaries.class%"
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ]] 

#MyCommand.php
$request = $this->getContainer()->get('request');
$categories = $this->getContainer()->get('dg.glossary.controller')->setGlossaryAction($request);

#GlossaryController
/**
  * @Route("set_glossary/{type}",name="set_glossary_watches")
  * @Template("xxxBundle:Glossary:glossary.html.twig")
  */
 public function setGlossaryAction(Request $request) {
  ...
}
```

With this configuration I have this error

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InactiveScopeException]
  You cannot create a service ("request") of an inactive scope ("request").
```

How Can I call my controller with different parameter (type param) ?

Comment: you can't access request in command because command has no knowledge about request (this is http/browser specific)

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski Thanks, Can I simulate $request ? like `$request = $this->getContainer()->get('request');
        $request->attributes->set('type', 'mytype');         $categories = $this->getContainer()->get('dg.glossary.controller')->setGlossaryAction($request);` in my Command  o something like this ? Have I to create two or more route for "each" $type ?

Comment: There is [an official guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#simulating-a-request) about how to simulate a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in you commande

```
$this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
$this->getContainer()->set('request', new Request(), 'request');
```

Comment: perfect ! it works. My Final Code is:
`$this->getContainer()->enterScope('request');
        $this->getContainer()->set('request', new Request(), 'request');

        $request = $this->getContainer()->get('request');
        $request->attributes->set('type', 'myTpe');

        $categories = $this->getContainer()->get('dg.glossary.controller')->setGlossaryAction($request);`

Can you explain little bit?

Comment: Request is http/browser specific as said Tomasz Madeyski. We just create it in command line.